# Pass a unique ID to Square and get that ID back on response

Tags: square-connect

I am working in iOS / Objective C. I am building a JSON string and just using that to open `square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=JSON` which opens the app. I can process payment and sent back to my app.

But I have a disconnect. How does my app know what transaction goes with whatever item?

For example:  I rent cars. I have several cars in my inventory. I select "Car 4" and bring up the payment screen. Let the use pay and go back.

How can I send an id to square and then back to the app saying, that the payment was for "Car 4"?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into notes if you want the itemization to be visible in your Square Dashboard. From [Squares API documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-ios):

> This note is included in the itemizations field of Payment objects
>   returned by the List Payments and Retrieve Payment endpoints.

If you are looking to do item and inventory management, or pull prices from an item, you'll need to use the [Square Item APIs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#items-overview).

Comment: Hmm I did add a Notes value but it never showed up in the square app.

Comment: Which app? Does it show up in your online dashboard? If you retrieve the transaction, does it show up?

Comment: If you use the REST APIs to retrieve the transaction, does it show up?